# apt-get upgrade segfault!

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, apt, aptitude

I installed ubuntu server 10.04 and booted as normal.

Some time later, I booted the server and tried to install a new package/upgrade the existing packages using:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ntp
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

I checked the system log `/var/log/messages` and found these entries:

```
kernel: [ 5586.184028] apt-get[3864]: segfault at 7fb5e078477b ip 00007fb5da82223c sp 00007fffa943b430 error 6 in libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8.0[7fb5da7e1000+c5000]
kernel: [ 5682.494467] aptitude[3973]: segfault at 7f06d4c4d77b ip 00007f06d063723c sp 00007fff5feb8540 error 6 in libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8.0[7f06d05f6000+c5000]
kernel: [ 5991.238428] apt-get[4181]: segfault at 7f809c17e77b ip 00007f809621c23c sp 00007fff740deb30 error 6 in libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8.0[7f80961db000+c5000]
```

Also, I got the same error while trying to use `aptitude safe-upgrade` as it is clear from the log file.

How can this be fixed without system re-installation?

Comment: You might have to download a fresh copy of apt as a deb file and reinstall it using dpkg -i.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, try this command (from terminal) as root:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

And try `apt-get upgrade` again. If the problem still persist, you probably found a bug. Go to launchpad [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) and report your problem. Remember to include details like Ubuntu server version or any other relevant information.

Thanks!

Comment: `apt-get check` might be a more gentle way of clearing the database error. If that fails, removing the cache as crncosta suggests should hurt nothing.

Comment: It worked after removing the .bin files as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First I tried

```
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

as mentioned above.

Then I was still getting crashes when I was trying to install/remove something.
Either with apt-get or with aptitude.

It was always a segfault in `libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8.0`.

It turned out that one memory module was corrupt (checked it using memtest86).

After fixing that, I still was getting the same segfaults, so:

1. Fetched the `apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.7_i386.deb` in `/tmp`
2. Extract

   ```
   cd /tmp
   ar xv apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.7_i386.deb
   ```
3. Moved the correct file to the correct place

   ```
   cd /tmp/usr/lib
   mv -vi libapt-pkg-libc6.10-6.so.4.8* /usr/lib/
   ```

all right now.

Answer (score -3):

fixed the problem  of aptitude(segmentation fault)：

1. my PC running  debian wheezy and get segmentation fault  run aptitude
2. vi /etc/apt/source.list
3. copy an source and correct for sid(复制一条源，把wheezy改成sid保存)
4. apt-get update
5. apt-get install aptitude
6. my aptitude is ok.