# Segmentation fault while running apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to run

```
apt-get update
```

It gives an error

```
Reading package lists... Error!
Segmentation fault
```

What could be the root cause of this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try with `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @anandmbs Forgetting to use `sudo` shouldn't result in a segfault.

Comment: I have already logged in as root. And I did try it using sudo. But still I find Reading package lists... Error!

Comment: @edwinksl yes the access should be denied but should not result in errors

Comment: Any good with `apt-get check` ??

Comment: @SeverusTux it returns >Failed to fork

Comment: Can you try `sudo rm  /var/cache/apt/*.bin` followed by updating again?

Comment: please paste the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` .

Comment: Contents of sources.list

Comment: Related : http://askubuntu.com/q/14550/497359

Comment: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

Comment: Do a memtest. http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: @SeverusTux I followed the link u suggested and it still welcomes me with Failed to fork error.  It guess its because of some faulty memory allocations

Comment: @fkraiem i found my machine is running out of memory. only 267mb of my RAM is free. Could that be the reason?

Comment: 267MB is plenty. What you want to check is that your RAM is not faulty.

Comment: I am new to Linux community. trying to learn Linux,running it as a guest machine on my Hyper-V. I allocated 2gb of RAM to it. I cant afford more because I have few other guest machines running on my Hyper-V and I have a total of 8gb RAm

Comment: @fkraiem do u think its running on a faulty RAM?

Comment: That is possible, which is why you should run memtest to check it.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in sources.list  I had duplicate source lists. So it was trying to read them again and again and failing to fork. I rebooted my machine. Deleted the duplicate sources. Its working all fine and good

Comment: You should mention where these sources.list is located.

Comment: It will typically be in: `/etc/apt/sources.list`.