# Getting segfault on libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 22.04, segmentation-fault

I send bug reports for apt-get failures. Since apt-get fails, is there a way for me to get updates for this segfault?

```
Hardware Model MSIMS-7865
Memory 8.0 GiB
Processor AMD Athlon 5370 apu with radeon r3x4
Graphics AMD Kabini
Disk Capacity 1.0 TB
OS Name Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OS Type 64-bit
Gnome Version 42.2
Windowing System X11

 4:23:21 PM kernel: apport-gtk[13889]: segfault at 7fc31b51e8e0 ip 00007fb210e54517 sp 00007fb20ca98360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fb210d7f000+13b000]
 4:22:18 PM kernel: apt-get[13818]: segfault at 7fc4a9d328e0 ip 00007fb3975f4517 sp 00007ffcd5eca0d0 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fb39751f000+13b000]
 1:54:29 PM kernel: apt-get[10768]: segfault at 7f26c95c88e0 ip 00007f15b6e8a517 sp 00007ffe6cbd8270 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f15b6db5000+13b000]
12:39:11 PM kernel: apport-gtk[9017]: segfault at 7f23276e28e0 ip 00007f123c4a9517 sp 00007f123651e360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f123c3d4000+13b000]
12:38:25 PM kernel: traps: apt-get[8923] general protection fault ip:7ff8f1e6c517 sp:7ffcf58bdb90 error:0 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7ff8f1d97000+13b000]
11:09:23 AM kernel: apt-get[4791]: segfault at 7fe6fb5cc8e0 ip 00007fd5e8e8e517 sp 00007ffc68f50f90 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fd5e8db9000+13b000]
10:59:32 AM kernel: apport-gtk[4561]: segfault at 7f38f76e28e0 ip 00007f2803ab2517 sp 00007f2801c63360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f28039dd000+13b000]
10:59:15 AM kernel: update-manager[4507]: segfault at 7fff7eee18e0 ip 00007fee712ac517 sp 00007ffce3877b90 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fee711d7000+13b000]
10:59:01 AM kernel: apport-gtk[4482]: segfault at 7f33832e28e0 ip 00007f228f307517 sp 00007f228d125360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f228f232000+13b000]
10:58:44 AM kernel: software-proper[4417]: segfault at 7f1a036e28e0 ip 00007f090ecfe517 sp 00007ffd11e9c560 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f090ec29000+13b000]
10:58:22 AM kernel: apport-gtk[4386]: segfault at 7f6496ee18e0 ip 00007f5392b29517 sp 00007f5390841360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f5392a54000+13b000]
10:58:05 AM kernel: software-proper[4315]: segfault at 7fb5472e28e0 ip 00007fa450746517 sp 00007fff270cb310 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fa450671000+13b000]
10:48:25 AM kernel: apport-gtk[3777]: segfault at 7fa1a76e28e0 ip 00007f90b9db8517 sp 00007f90b8828360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f90b9ce3000+13b000]
10:47:36 AM kernel: apport-gtk[3543]: segfault at 7f5b935d98e0 ip 00007f4a9f10d517 sp 00007f4a9d85f360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f4a9f038000+13b000]
10:46:06 AM kernel: apport-gtk[3228]: segfault at 7f699b6e28e0 ip 00007f589248d517 sp 00007f588dfdc360 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f58923b8000+13b000]
10:45:18 AM kernel: PK-Backend[3045]: segfault at 7fd1cb6e28e0 ip 00007fc0d0160517 sp 00007fc0c998c860 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7fc0d008b000+13b000]
10:45:18 AM kernel: apt-check[3034]: segfault at 7fa57a0dd8e0 ip 00007f9467a46517 sp 00007ffe886a2d60 error 4 in libapt-pkg.so.6.0.0[7f9467971000+13b000]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Ran
`sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin`
Then ran LOTS of updates via the Ubuntu software updater.

Long story:

- Thanks Pilot6 for correcting the formatting on my original post.
- Was disapointed that no recommended solutions were offered for 3 weeks.
- Most online solutions to repair Ubuntu packages used apt. All of my attempts to use apt on my computer segfaulted.
- Finally ran across a 12 year old recommendation to purge cache files (shown above). This was a simple fix. I thought that I had a corrupted libapt-pkg.so executable.
  [apt-get upgrade segfault!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14550/apt-get-upgrade-segfault)
  Thanks to the authors for recommending that fix 12 years ago.